# Can you use DllImport (Add-type) in Powershell without casting?

Tags: c#, powershell, casting, dllimport

I'm trying to use .net's MoveFileEx function from Powershell but DllImport seems to require casting all parameters to a certain type.

I have this code thanks to http://poshcode.org/2196:

```
$MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT = 0x00000004
$memberDefinition = @'
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true, CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern bool MoveFileEx(string lpExistingFileName, string lpNewFileName, int dwFlags);
'@
$type = Add-Type -Name MoveFileUtils -MemberDefinition $memberDefinition -PassThru
```

To MOVE a file at boot time, this works fine:

```
$result = $type::MoveFileEx($Path, $destination, $MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT)
```

To DELETE a file at boot time, I thought this would work.

```
$result = $type::MoveFileEx($Path, $null, $MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT)
```

But I get this error:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. 
At line:2 char:1 + $result = $type::MoveFileEx($Path, $null, $MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT) +
 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~‌​~~~~~~~~~~~ + 
CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException + 
FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

This is because lpNewFileName is cast as string in the DllImport line above

Is there a way to rework the $memberDefinition (aka the c# code) to NOT cast lpNewFileName as string?

Or to import the MoveFileEx function twice, one with lpNewFileName cast as string and the second with lpNewFileName cast as null?

**Update 1:** I tried this

```
$NullValue = [NullString]::Value
$result = $type::MoveFileEx($Path, $NullValue, $MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT)
```

and got this error:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:4 char:6
+                     $result = $type::MoveFileEx($Path, $NullValue, $MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT ...
+                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Looks like I will need to write a wrapper function in c# to call the same MoveFileEx depending if I want to move or delete a file. Yay!

**Update 2** As requested: fully self-contained code to demonstrate the problem.

```
$Path = "C:\ProgramData\DeleteMe.txt"
Set-Content -Path $Path -Value "Test file for you!"

$memberDefinition = @'
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true, CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern bool MoveFileEx(string lpExistingFileName, string lpNewFileName, int dwFlags);
'@
$type = Add-Type -Name MoveFileUtils -MemberDefinition $memberDefinition -PassThru

[Int32]$MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT = 0x00000004
$NullValue = [NullString]::Value  #I read that c# may not like $null b/c c# sees $null as an object. (Stay buggy MS)
$result = $type::MoveFileEx($Path, $NullValue, $MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT)
#If successful, PendingFileRenameOperations value is created at: 
# [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Session Manager]
$Destination = "C:\ProgramData\DeleteMe.new"
$result = $type::MoveFileEx($Path, $Destination, $MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT)
```

**Now problem has disappeared! No more errors.
WTH..Thank you?!**

It seems the **[NullString]::Value** is the key but it failed the first time I tried it.

Comment: if it did not cast it as a string what should it be instead?

Comment: Undefined or not casted if possible. To move, lpNewFileName must be a string. To delete, lpNewFileName must be null. I think I'll have to write a wrapper function for MoveFileEx to get around this limitation of DllImport

Comment: A null cast to a string should still be a null

Comment: That might work in pure C# code but if I try: 
$result = $type::MoveFileEx($Path, $null, $MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT) 

I get: 
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:2 char:1
+ $result = $type::MoveFileEx($Path, $null, $MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Comment: That information would have been useful to put in the question itself, you should edit your question and put it in there. Also update your question with a complete example we could copy and paste in to powershell to test ourselves of the code that causes the error.

Comment: Can you please please show all of lines in a single code example from script entry point to leading up to the line that is causing the exception, I would like to see the leadup to your `$result = $type::MoveFileEx($Path, $NullValue, $MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT)` call.